# Failed to execute 'measure' on 'Performance': The mark '<yourMarkName>' does not exist

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, browser

I want to measure the duration of my async operation and I'm setting marks for that. The first mark I set before the async operation start and the end mark with measure I set in the callback of async operation like this:

```
performance.mark('async start');
someAsyncFunction(function callback() {
   performance.mark('async end');
   performance.measure('async operation', 'async start', 'async end');
});
```

But it gives me this error:

> Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Failed to execute 'measure' on
> 'Performance': The mark 'async start' does not exist.

I tried to find a similar answer but didn't find anything about it.